# Java: Testing a Resizeable Circular Array Queue

Tags: java, testing, circular-list

I'm trying to implement a circular array queue which can be resized, in order to meet a series of tests.

However I repeatedly fail the tests mainly due to the queue being the wrong size after En-Queuing  and De-Queueing, but additionally because the queue failed to resize when it was expected to do so.

I appreciate that initialising the size of the queue to 1000 may be a mistake, but even after debugging it I can't find out what's causing the failure.

If you could help me identify the reasons for the test failures that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see why it is behaving differently to what you think it should.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the code once you have found an answer!

Comment: -1 for removing the code. This user seems to have a habit of doing that. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22160555/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the `noItems` method:

```
@Override
public int noItems() {
    if(rear > front)
        return rear - front;
    return N - front + rear;
}
```

After 1000 insertions the Queue size is now 2000, but `N` is `final` and is still 1000. Change N by `Queue.length`.

PS: Java conventions recommend variables and attributes should start with lowercase: at first glance I was looking for the Queue class definition and its length static field :P